# Probability from a pack of balls

Tags: probability

Two balls are drawn,in succession,from a pack of 10 red,30 white,20 blue and 15 orange balls,replacement being made after each drawing.What's the probability that they're 'either red or white or both'?

Comment: What have you tried?  What, for example, is the probability that the first is red or white?

Comment: I've tried this this combination all analysis :10C2/75C2+30C2/75C2+(10C1*30C1)/75C2